# Examples of "Hidden Gems" in late answers

Tags: support

When reviewing late answers, one can see this tip:

> This is a late answer to an old question provided by a new user. Watch
>   for **hidden gems**, non-answers, and spam.

I have doubts on what the **hidden gems** part means. What exactly should one be looking for? A few examples (the most recurring or offending ones at least) might clear up the concept.

Comment: Whenever in doubt regarding a word or a term in Stack Overflow, refer to the [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) :)

Comment: Unfortunately, "hidden gem" isn't listed in the glossary.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe that a "hidden gem" in this case refers to an answer that's surprisingly outstanding in quality, especially coming from a new user.

Such answers are rare to come by, plus you don't often find these when sifting through a series of usually low-quality answers or "thanks", "me too!" non-answers (which are the norm when it comes to late answers by new users).

Comment: I actually read it as sarcasm... Especially since its in a list of generally unwelcome content... More along the lines of the urban dictionary's definition...

Comment: Oh OK, I thought a _hidden gem_ was a negative thing, like some weird looking link or something. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Nice, I stole your wording to update the glossary. Hope you don't mind? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No problem. Just FYI, the term wasn't coined by Stack Exchange - it's a common idiom in English.

Comment: Not so common, couldn't find any reliable source; on the contrary - urban dictionary gave not-so-pleasant meaning to this term. :D

Comment: Googling for hidden gems list places where the only meaning could be positive I thnk urban dictionary is wrong here

Answer (score 5):

I've cooked up [a data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82892/gems-in-late-answers) that finds not-so-hidden gems: answers that new users made within a week of registering, to questions that were at least six-months old at the time, that have accumulated more than a net of 25 votes.

The top one is the only post by that user, and now has over 600 up-votes.  It's a bit short, so maybe the query could be enhanced to limit only to answers that are 'worth a read'.

Comment: Nice, but this won't help finding any *new* gems. :)